# facebook Pay Dialog in Corona sdk

Tags: facebook, lua, coronasdk

I am trying to show the facebook Pay Dialog in my app using the facebook library of Corona SDK. 
I couldn't find any documentation for this specific dialog in corona's documentation, so I have no idea what I am doing wrong.

this is my code:

```
local requestID = generateUUID(64)
local product = "https://myappname.appspot.com/opengraph/coin.html")
facebook.showDialog("pay", { action = "purchaseitem", product = product, quantity = "10", request_id = requestID })
```

When the code runs the dialog opens and displays the error message: 
"An error occurred. Please try again later", 
and when I close the dialog the response I get is: "App not enabled on mobile".

Also, I use the showDialog function for sharing and invite in my app and that work properly.

In the web version of my game, this is the implementation (and it works):

```
FB.ui({
      method: 'pay',
      action: 'purchaseitem',
      product: "https://myappname.appspot.com/opengraph/coin.html",
      request_id: requestID,
      quantity: "10"
    },
    verifyPaymentCallback
  );
```

Comment: Not an expert, but I think it might be that the 'App (is) not enabled on mobile'? Sounds to me like the app settings in your facebook dev has not been properly setup.

Comment: I checked the settings in facebook and couldn't find anything relevant

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks to me like this dialog is only available to web apps:

```
Additional notes:

     Only Canvas apps on Facebook.com can open the this dialog.
```

They don't provide any examples or mentions of doing this in Objective-C or Java for native apps.  There is only the reference to the Javascript/HTML version.  While they do mention "mobile" payments, it's not about apps, its about in some foreign country's some carriers handle micro payment billing over SMS or other means of billing users.